# Open Visual Studio Solution file only in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I was using .NET Core API project with 2.2 Framework in VS 2017. Now we have migrated all the .NET Core API Projects to 3.0 Framework.I have both VS 2017 and 2019 installed in my machine. When we click on ".sln" file it gets openend in VS 2017. But i want the .sln file to be openend in VS 2019.
Please let me know the changes required to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you right-click the solution and see a list of programs to open with? If so, then select the version of VS you want. Once opened in VS2019, a "Save" should set the default to that for the next time. (Or open VS2019 from the Start Menu, then open the solution from inside.)

Answer (score 8):

1. Right-click on the .sln file
2. From the popup menu click on "Open with" and in the submenu click on "Choose another app"

[image: Context menu screenshot]

3. In the splash window select "Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector", don't forget to **tick** the "**Always use this app to open .sln files**" checkbox, and click "OK".

[image: How do you want to open this file? - screenshot]

4. If prompted to save changes to the "devenv.sln" file, save changes.

In this way, a **double click** on a **.sln** should open it with *the version of Visual Studio that was used to create it*.

Answer (score 7):

For one, you can delete the solution file and create a new one `dotnet new sln`.

Assuming you have .NET Core 3.0 sdk installed and active (in case of `globa.json` being present), it should create you an *.sln file for VS 2019.

Alternatively edit your sln and change the first few lines to

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.29512.175
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

thats the sln header VS 2019.4 (16.4) creates on new solutions

Comment: I tried the above steps. It works only once or twice. After that the solution gets opened in VS 2017.

Comment: Can't be. You must be doing something different. Are you working with multiple people who save/override the changes when they check it out (and save) in their old VIsual Studio Versions maybe and their commits roll it back? Otherwise set the minimum version to 16.0.29512.175, this should prevent VS 2017 to open it in the first place

Answer (score 3):

**Open Visual Studio 2019 and select File-->Open** than browse to the solution file that should be ported to VS2019 to open it.
After the solution file was successfully opened in VS2019, chose to Save All.
From now on, your solution file will be opened with VS2019 once you doubleclick solution file in file explorer.

P.S.
Editing solution file manually to update VS version is not recommended because it does not respect possible structural changes of the solution file that may appear between VS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Or,

- create a shortcut to the .sln file
- right-click the shortcut, choose Properties, General
- Opens with, click Change and select Visual Studio 2019

(note - this only changes the shortcut, not the .sln itself, but it's a quick safe fix)